# Would there be a magnetic null point of a flat coil when pulsed dc is passed through it?

Tags: electromagnetism, coil, pulse

Flat coil is only of a few turns and does not go upto the center and also has a consistent pulsed dc passing though it.

Shouldnt the electromagnetic radiation cancel out each other and have null effect in the center of the coil ? I understand that energy cannot be destroyed but shouldnt magnetic effect be nullified?

Comment: No. Viewed from the center of the coil, each winding has the same direction of current (clockwise or counterclockwise), so their respective magnetic fields add up. And you are dealing with static fields, so radiation effects are negligible.

Comment: Like I commented in below answer what if it is only of few turns and it does not go upto the center

Comment: So if in the center magnetic field is highest wouldnt its magnetic effect still be neutral?

Comment: Google Biot-Savart law. It gives direction and magnitude caused by an infinitesimal current element.

Answer (score 2):

I'm puzzled that you think it 'should'.

Consider all the current elements that make up the coil. Use the 'right hand rule' (google or wikipedia, or both) to understand the direction of field in the middle of the coil that each element generates. Then notice that they all add up rather than cancel.

[image]

It doesn't matter what angle round the coil they are, or what radius, **all** the axial components of field from the circumferential currents will add up in the middle of the coil. It doesn't matter whether the sides are round as shown, or straight as in a square coil, the circumferential component of the current will generate the central field. All that matters is that the current goes 'round' the axis. It doesn't matter how many times it goes round, once or a hundred times, or any integer N.

Comment: By a few turns I meant that Flat coil is not upto the center and only there for a few turns. something like this but with fewer turns:https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQnCm0hllxh3YF2AujsYn7cYwo05XBHxGsf9wc18v7hjJXT2M8hSQ

Comment: Same physics applies evenfor a coil of a single turn.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a single conductor carrying current thus: -

[image]

When viewed from above you can see that with current flowing downwards, it generates a magnetic field that is clockwise

Now, consider a single turn coil and the resulting direction of the magnetic fields produced from opposite sides of that coil: -

[image]

The grey flat plane is just showing the direction of the magnetic field in that plane. Can you see that they are additive through the centreline of the coil?

Each "turn" in a multi-turn coil will produce a magnetic field in the same direction providing that the turns are orientated to have current in the same direction. It doesn't matter if the turns are stacked like a solenoid or are planar (flat).

Taken to extremes, if the applied pulse were very short in duration and applied repeatedly, transmission line effects could cause some magnetic field cancellation and a very complex shaped magnetic field.

Comment: They are additive but if a piece of metal was placed in center would it move to either direction ?

Comment: A piece of iron would move to where the field is strongest and this is always closer to the coils so, yes it would move from the off-centre position. One constraint - if the iron was a regular round shape and placed dead centre then it would find equilibrium even though the slightest movement or vibration would send it off towards one side or the other.